# Permission ERRNO13 when saving image with Python Launcher, not IDLE -- Python

Tags: python, permissions, cairo, temporary-files

I have a turtle program that creates an image. I have the following code to save the canvas as svg. (I don't include the turtle program here).

```
import os
import tempfile
import shutil

name = input("What would you like to name it? \n")
nameSav = name + ".png"
tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()                   # create a temporary directory
tmpfile = os.path.join(tempdir, 'tmp.svg')    # name of file to save SVG to
ts = turtle.getscreen().getcanvas()
canvasvg.saveall(tmpfile, ts)
with open(tmpfile) as svg_input, open(nameSav, 'wb') as png_output:
    cairosvg.svg2png(bytestring=svg_input.read(), write_to=png_output)
shutil.rmtree(tmpdir)     # clean up temp file(s)
```

This works in IDLE. The canvas is saved as a png just fine. If I run it with the Python Launcher for Windows, I get:

```
     with open(tmpfile) as svg_input, open(nameSav, 'wb') as png_output:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test.png'
```

test.png is the name I chose at this point when I saved (ie, NameSav).
So what's up with this? Why doesn't IDLE get this error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that permission is denied in saving `test.png` in the **current working directory** of the Python launcher, which would be the location of the launcher exe. Give the input prompt a full path, like `C:\Users\Spam\Documents\test.png`, or use `os.path.join` to prepend an appropriate directory in front of `nameSav`.

Why IDLE works is that IDLE has a different current working directory, that pointing to a folder where writes are allowed.

Say, you want to save the resulting image to the `images` subfolder of the folder containing your script, you can calculate the target file name as

```
from os import path

filename = input("What would you like to name it? \n")
if not filename.lower().endswith('.png'):
    filename += '.png'

target_path = path.join(path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__)), 'images', filename)

with ... open(target_path, 'wb') as png_output:
    ...
```

Comment: How would I indicate an input path if I wanted to move the launcher or send this file to a friend? The path might not exist, so how can I, for example, just designate it to save the image in a folder called images inside the launchers folder?

Comment: Ok I figured how to save it in the same folder as the script with
`os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`, but how can I save it inside the folder Images (which is inside the scripts folder)?